# Jest, Enzyme. Как тестировать рефы?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, тестирование, jest, enzyme

Я занимаюсь тестированием метода жизненного цикла componentDidUpdate. У меня есть такой код:

```
public componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
if (this.rowsIsUpdated) {
  this.setState({
    headers: this.updateWidthAndEditors()
  });

  const node = this._domNodeRef.current.querySelector('.react-grid-Canvas');
  node.scrollTo(0, node.scrollHeight);
  this.rowsIsUpdated = false;
}
// Если пришли данные размер которых не совпадает с тем что было, то устанавливаем новую длину данных
if (this.props.rows.length !== prevProps.rows.length) {
  this.setState({ countRows: this.props.rows.length, height: this.props.height });
  // ставим флаг для последующего скролла вниз к добавленным строкам, после рендера
  this.rowsIsUpdated = true;
}
}
```

Я написал тест с использованием setProps. для обновления props rows.

```
it('change component content', () => {
const wrapper = mount(<DataGrid rows={rows} headers={fields} width={500} height={500} />) as any;

wrapper.setProps({ rows: rows2 }, () => {
  expect(wrapper.instance().rowsIsUpdated).toBe(false);
});
});
```

Тест останавливается на вызове node.scrollTo, выдавая ошибку "node.scrollTo is not a function".
Кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобными проблемами? Я не могу решить эту задачу уже несколько дней.

Я пробовал также использовать shallow за место mount в тесте и дважды вызывать setProps, но тогда появляется ошибка "maximum call stack size".